# Настроить DNS для домена

Tags: dns

В панеле управления доменами 2 поля     **А-записи для домена в DNS**

На хостинге просят:

> Пожалуйста убедитесь, что записи DNS указывают на: ns1.biz.nf
>   ns2.biz.nf

Как я понимаю нужно ввести IP . *Где мне взять этот ip если мне адреса такие дают а не цифры?* Ну я уже полазил по инету вроде сделал но я не уверен что то! Потому что мне выдает в админке уже хостинга "Домен не реплицирован" хотя если зайти по адресу вроде заработало все. Или надо подождать день, потому что написано в админке хостинга что 24 часа чо то там

Answer (score 0):

`A`-записи указывают на сервер, на который перенаправляются к домену, в них должен быть прописан IP-адрес. DNS-сервера, ответственные за Ваш домен, указываются в **`NS`**-записях, как раз в виде полного доменного имени. Вот, например, настройки одного из моих доменов зарегистрированных в REG.ru:

[image: Настройка DNS записей 1]

Вот другой пример, более крупный, на регистраторе GoDaddy.com:

[image: Настройка DNS записей 2]

Обратите внимание, что поддомен **`@`** обозначает основной домен Вашего сайта (вроде `mysite.com`), а другое значение его поддомен (**`www`** – `www.mysite.com`). То есть, можно указать разные серверы, которые будут обрабатывать основной домен и поддомены. **`NS`** записи достаточно указать только для основного домена **`@`**.